# How to run a raw-disk Virtualbox VM when using UEFI?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I have a dual-boot setup on my computer with Windows 10 and Linux (Arch, if relevant).  I'm trying to virtualize my on-disk Linux install in Windows (and plan on doing the opposite direction once I get this way to work).  I've successfully made a raw disk; I just can't boot from it.

I can't seem to access my kernel in my EFI System Partition. My question is, how can I access my EFI System Partition in Virtualbox so I can boot from it?  Should I give up on this approach and do something entirely different?

Thanks for any assistance you are able to provide!

Comment: I actually did this. I had a Thinkpad that dual booted Ubuntu and Windows, each of which loaded a VM of the other. I used legacy boot, not EFI due to the exact issues you are experiencing. I switched before setting up the dual boot, but you might be able to switch to legacy, let a windows startup repair thumb disk do its magic and finally fix grub. One warning: If you are running Windows, and have the Linux VM up, DO NOT let the linux VM mount the windows disk. You may be tempted to let it see that partition as well to copy files. ntfs-3g on a running Windows partition FUBARs things quick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the "Enable EFI" option is checked in the machine settings under the System menu.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgc8E.png)